# Excel Export from Access via VBA changing Row Height

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export a query from Access to Excel and I can do so successfully. However when I open the document, the row height on almost all the rows has increased to contain the text they contain (which wrapped). This requires the rows and columns to be manually adjusted to get the rows back to the default height.

Is anyone aware of a way to expand the columns when exporting to Excel rather than the rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off the "Wrap Text" option for the cells the text will not expand the row height.  Is there any reason you can't select all of the cells and change the row heights all at once?